# Raspberry Pi Bridge: I need to send a "fake" internet response to an Internet appliance

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi already configured as a bridge and working just fine.  The principle use is to monitor and capture traffic from a small internet appliance.  That appliance is basically receiving radio transmission from a set of local sensors and then posting the values to an internet server. As a bridge, I'm "reading" the transmissions with a Python program as they pass through and processing some of the sensor data locally for my own use.

The problem is that appliance seems to need to have the Internet working to function correctly, ie it needs to think the internet is up and its messages are being received by the server. The other day we had a 10 hour Internet outage and I lost all of that data.

The Internet appliance does not seem to be waiting for an "I got it" response from the server for every transmission, but rather seems to need an occasional "I got it" or something from the server.

Thus, when the internet is down for an extended period, the appliance stops processing the local sensor signals, even though the sensors are still transmitting, and stops trying to post the information to the internet server. And, I stop getting data to process locally.

My idea is to try to construct a "fake message from the server" and just periodically send it to that Internet appliance, regardless of the state of the Internet.  While I can see all of the traffic to and from the Internet appliance, I have no idea how to construct such a record nor how to send it to the appliance via Python.

Any thoughts? Thanks...RDK

Answer (score 0):

Communication to the appliance (through the internet) may be done with the `socket` module.  See https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html

Comment: OK, I'll read up on this.  In my case, is the program running on my Pi Bridge the client or the server?  Recall that the message I want to send to the internet appliance will be a copy of one that it is being routinely getting from the server, ie the target for the sensor data packets from the Internet appliance.

Comment: The program will run on the PI Bridge.  As for the contents of the message, it depends entirely on what the distant server expects; there is no general answer.

Comment: I guess my comment was not clear.  The Internet Appliance is on the subnet of my network which the Pi is bridging.  The server communication I want to fake is from a Server which is on the Real Internet and remote from my network. As far as I can figure the Internet Appliance is looking for a periodic message from the Internet Server but not one for each transmission that leaves the Internet Appliance.  So my question again, do I configure the Python program on my Pi as a "client" or as a "server" for the periodic fake message to the Internet Appliance? Thanks

Comment: On your Pi, you should use a "client socket".